# Performing find function to search inside the main state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, find, state

I am trying to apply a search bar. User requested to type and will search inside the main state to get specific data based on the data id user will be navigated to showScreen to present the specific data 
It's two options either browse the main data available or search using the bar

** How can I do it either by highlighting the data so he press and navigate or get the id and navigate him directly ? **

this is my code

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, 
        Text, 
        StyleSheet, 
        FlatList , 
        TouchableOpacity, 
        ImageBackground, 
        Dimensions
    } from 'react-native';
import {Input} from 'react-native-elements';
import Spacer from '../compnents/Spacer';
import PlaySound from '../PlaySound';
import myApi from '../API/myApi';
import Lalezar from '../Fonts/Lalezar';
import {FontAwesome} from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { navigate } from '../NavigationRef';



const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;

const DataListScreen = ({navigation}) => {

    const [state, setState] = useState();
    const [term, setTerm] = useState('');

    const myData = async () => {
        const response = await myApi.get('/arabic');
        setState(response.data);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        myData();
    }, []);


        const searchData = state;
        const searchResults = () => {
        searchData.find(t => t.id === id);
        setTerm(term.id);
        const id = term.find(t => t.id === id);
        navigate('Show' , {id});
        console.log(term);
        }


     return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground source = {require('../../assets/Featured_5_rvdq97.jpg')}
        style = {styles.backGround}
        />
        <View style = {styles.searchBar} >
            <FontAwesome name = 'search' size = {25} style = {{marginLeft : 30, marginTop : 5}}/>
            <Input 
            inputStyle = {styles.searchInput}
            placeholder = 'بحث'
            placeholderTextColor = 'white'
            value = {term}
            onChangeText = {setTerm}
            onEndEditing = {searchResults}
            />
        </View>
             <View style = {{position : 'absolute'}}>
            <Lalezar title = {'List of All Data '} 
            style = {styles.textHead}
            />
            </View>
            <Spacer />
            <FlatList 
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator = {false}
            data = {state}
            numColumns = {2}
            keyExtractor = {(state) => state.id}
            style = {styles.flatList}
            renderItem = {({item}) => {
                return (
                    <View style = {styles.bigContainer}>
                    <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress ={() => navigation.navigate('Show' , {
                        title : item.title, id : item.id, content : item.content
                    })}>
                    <View style= {styles.listContainer}>
                        <Text style = {styles.textList}>   {item.title} </Text>

                    <Spacer />
                    <PlaySound link = {item.audio_url} 
                        style = {styles.sound}
                        />
                    </View>

                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                );
            }}
            />
        </View>
    );
};



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container : {
        backgroundColor : '#d2d6d5',
        alignContent : 'center'
    },
    bigContainer : {
        flex : 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderWidth : 1,
        borderRadius : 7,
        margin : (SCREEN_WIDTH / 80),
        marginHorizontal : (SCREEN_WIDTH / 75),
        height : (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 6)
    },  
    textList : {
        fontSize : (SCREEN_WIDTH / 28),
        fontWeight : 'bold',
        margin : (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 75)
    },
    textHead : {
       marginLeft : 50
    },
    backGround : {
        width : SCREEN_WIDTH,
        height : (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 5),
        opacity : 0.7
    },
    flatList : {
        marginTop : -(SCREEN_HEIGHT / 15),
    },
    searchBar : {
        flex : 1,
        flexDirection : 'row',
        position : 'absolute',
        marginTop : 60,
        marginLeft : 12,
        borderWidth : 2,
        borderRadius : 7,
        height : 45,
        justifyContent : 'center',
        marginRight : 40
    },
    searchInput : {
        alignSelf : 'center',
        marginRight : 25,
        color : 'blue',
        fontSize : 25,
        fontWeight : 'bold',
    }
});


export default DataListScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

This function works well

```
   const searchTitle = () => {
        const results = state.values();
        for (const value of results) {
           if (value.title == term) {
             setVlaue(results);
             console.log(value);

            const id = value.id;
            const title = value.title;
           navigate('Show', {id, title});
           }
        }    
    }
```

and then in search bar tags

```
<View style = {styles.searchBar} >
            <FontAwesome name = 'search' size = {25} style = {{marginLeft : 30, marginTop : 5}}/>
            <Input 
            inputStyle = {styles.searchInput}
            placeholder = 'بحث'
            placeholderTextColor = 'white'
            value = {term}
            onChangeText = {setTerm}
            onEndEditing = {searchTitle}
            />
```